# Why is my Oracle Bot only visible to my account?

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have setup a Skill bot on Oracle Cloud and configured the Facebook app to the Messenger channel on Oracle. Now, I can chat with the bot but only through my account. Trying to access the page on a different account brings a normal page and worse, isn't available when I log out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was something with the app's user roles.